# Bitwise operation to shift left AND change the right most bit?

Tags: c

I'm attempting to write a program which takes a string input of '0' and '1' from the user and then uses that given string to change each bit of another variable.

i.e.

```
char input[20];
unsigned short bits = 0;

printf("Enter a binary string of 16 bits.\n");

fgets(input, 20, stdin);
input[strlen(input) - 1] = '\0';
```

is what I have to get and store a two byte string from the user. I then want to take that string and manipulate the variable 'bits' to match what was entered.

So if the user entered 10011001 10011001 I would like to change the value of 'unsigned short bits' from all 0's to the matching value in binary.

My thinking right now is that I could loop through the input string and left shift 'bits' with each pass but as far as I know left shifting will always drop the left most bit and add a 0 as the right most bit.  Is there a way to add a 1 as the left most bit with some bitwise command I don't know of so that if the loop sees a '1' in the string it adds a one to the rightmost bit?

Comment: For each char of the string, shift `unsigned short bits` left and set bit 0 to the value in the string. If the input has fewer bits than needed it still works.

Comment: I don't think `input[strlen(input) - 1] = '\0';` is correct.

Comment: Deleted my previous comment because I think I misread your question.  However is "add a 1 as the left most bit" a typo?  Did you mean "right" here?

Comment: @LegendofPedro it can be but is not guaranteed to work. Please see [Removing trailing newline character from fgets() input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693776/removing-trailing-newline-character-from-fgets-input/28462221#28462221)

Comment: @WeatherVane that's good info. I was thinking about what happens if you pipe `echo ""` and have a zero-length input string without a newline.

Comment: @LegendofPedro similarly the last line of a redirected file might not end with newline.

Comment: Aside, consider what happens when the first character entered is a _null character_.    `input[strlen(input) - 1]` becomes a hacker exploit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `bits = (bits << 1);` to shift in a 0.
Use `bits = (bits << 1) | 1;` to shift in a 1.

Comment: This worked! thank you and everyone else for the quick replies.  I was almost there but I was using OR incorrectly in my loop.

Answer (score 1):

That would work.

In your loop, you first shift `bits` to the left and then `OR` 1 if the character is `1`:

```
bits |= 1;
```

Comment: Or just add 1 :)